# What causes the page store subscription to sometimes return an empty object in development mode with sveltekit in devmode wit vite?

Tags: vite, sveltekit

subscribing to page store sometimes results in an empty object

[image: debugging in chrome devtools shows an empty object]

This does not occur every time and only in development mode with vite as a dev server.

I tried to subscribe after the component is mounted as you see in the image, but that does not make difference. Sometimes clearing the browser cache resolves the issue but not always. I am really lost here because this is difficult to debug. It looks like some kind of race condition that the page object is not loaded yet. I access the development server through a cloud-flare tunnel with https. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should not manually subscribe to stores in components, just use `$page` to access store contents. Otherwise you add a subscription that should be cleaned up again.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  
What I need to do is manually reload the +page.server.ts from the page that has the  component because when a $page.url is changed within this component new data arrives in the $page.data object.

$: if($page.data.newdata) { ... process the new data here....}

if this is the right approach then just give a thumbs up :-)